# How to align CSS Input type Text Placeholder Image

Tags: css

[Link to Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faJq3.png)

as the image here , i just want to make the search icon to be placed in left side and after the search icon , placeholder text must be there , how can i just do that ?

Comment: there was scroll 100% , and i just decreased it to 3%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image is inside the field try

```
float:left;
padding-left:5px;
```

Hope I helped, or else paste your code at http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can simple add padding to the left side of your input and the placeholder will become indented.

```
input{
    background: url('http://placehold.it/16x16') no-repeat 10px 10px; /* Your background image */
    padding-left: 35px; /* Indent text and placeholder text */
}
```

[Here's a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rjjrh/1/)